# How we can Override Magento\CustomerCustomAttributes\view\templates\customer\form\edit.phtml in custom module

Tags: magento-2.2.1

I want to Override Magento\CustomerCustomAttributes\view\templates\customer\form\edit.phtml file in my custom module.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceBlock name="customer_edit">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">I95Dev_CustomerAttributeDisable::customer/form/edit.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>  
        </body>
```

This is the core code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="customer_form_template_handle"/>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="head.components">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="customercustomattributes_account_edit_head_components" template="Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes::js/components.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_edit">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes::customer/form/edit.phtml</argument>
        </action>
        <block class="Magento\CustomerCustomAttributes\Block\Form" template="Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes::form/userattributes.phtml" name="customer_form_user_attributes" cacheable="false">
            <action method="setFormCode">
                <argument name="code" xsi:type="string">customer_account_edit</argument>
            </action>
            <action method="setEntityModelClass">
                <argument name="code" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Model\Customer</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tutorial for override files in magento 2

1. [Override phtml file](https://webkul.com/blog/override-phtml-file-magento2/)
2. [Override Block, Model, Controller](https://webkul.com/blog/overriding-rewriting-classes-magento2/)

I hope it helps!

Comment: i know how to override phtml file, Actually this Magento\CustomerCustomAttributes\view\templates\customer\form\edit.phtml file is not overriding in my custom module, its working when I override it to in theme level.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: Which magento version are you using? i did't find any core module like `CustomerCustomAttributes`

Comment: Magento 2.2.1 EE

Comment: I have updated the core code

Comment: This block is already is override `<referenceBlock name="customer_edit">`  the original block you can find in `/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_edit.xml`

Comment: How can i achieve this please help me to override it to in my custom module

Comment: Let me try if i found something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85732/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-afreen).

Comment: What is your module? What you need to do exactly?